# Combine data from 2 "strange" tables

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Having the following Schema

[(ER of DataBase)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb3SN.jpg)
I am trying to create a query that

1. will show the title(`Movies`.`Title`) along with each movie's genre(`movie_Genres`.`movie_genre`) for each movie that..
2. that have been seen in *(a)* a  specific time period (lets say 2-3 days for ex. We can take those days from the `Tickets`.`ticket_date`) *(b)* by Male Customers(`Customer`.`customer_sec`) and *(c)* got rated more than 4 (rated_customerRation) by those customers.

I can get as close as the following query:

```
    SELECT 
       `movie_title`, `movie_Genres`.`movie_genre`
    FROM
       `Movies`
    INNER JOIN
       `movie_Genres` ON `mg_movie` = `movie_ID`
    INNER JOIN
       `Rated` ON `rated_movie_ID` = `movie_ID`     
    WHERE `rated_customerRatio` > 4 AND
    UNION
       (SELECT 
            `customer_sex`, `rated_customerRatio`
                 FROM
                    `Customer`
                    /* INNER JOIN
                    `cinema`.`Rated` ON `Rated`.`rated_customer_tabID` = `Customer`.`customer_tabID` 
                    */
                    INNER JOIN
                   `cinema`.`Tickets` ON `Tickets`.`ticket_customer_tabID`=`Customer`.`customer_tabID`
                WHERE
           `customer_sex` LIKE 'Male'
           /* AND rated_customerRatio > 4 */
            AND `Tickets`.`ticket_date` > '2016-02-16')
    GROUP BY `movie_title`;
```

Also I am thinking that I will have trouble, cause one movie can have more than one Genre, and I don't want double lines, for the same movie, in my outcome.

Any help will be taken into serious regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `WHERE movie.ID IN (Select movie.id...)` query to have unusual query relationships. i.e. if movie.id can be related to tickets

```
WHERE MovieID IN
(
SELECT 
    MovieID
FROM
    MovieTable
LEFT JOIN TICKETS ON MovieID = TICKETS.movieID
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER ON TICKETS.ID = CUSTOMER.ID
WHERE
CUSTOMER.customer_sex LIKE 'Male'
AND Tickets.ticket_date > '2016-02-16')
)
```

I dont know your DB schema but that should give you a rough idea on one way of sorting based on viewership of moves from tickets? 1 ticket should have 1 movie ID and 1 customer, so the relationship is pretty easy to figure out